# Django CMS - how views are created

Tags: django-cms

Im new to Django CMS and setting up a new project.

Would like to understand how the workflow works? I'm able to succesfully create a page and render it correctly but confused on how the views are created.

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom views then you need to create your own applications which can be hooked in to CMS really easily.

Take a look at the docs; http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/apphooks.html

Also, you can see an example of an application which can be integrated into CMS here; https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog/tree/develop/djangocms_blog